# Understanding the Convolution Operation as Described in the Deep Learning Book

Tags: convolution, neural-networks

I'm currently studying deep learning with the book *Deep Learning (Goodfellow et al., 2015)* and had a question regarding the convolution operation of convolutional neural networks (CNN's).

More specifically, on page 337 (in section 9.5: Variants of the Basic Convolution Function) the authors give a mathematical description of what the convolution operation looks like in the context of neural networks as follows:

> Let $\mathsf{K}$ be a 4-D tensor with element $K_{i, j, k, l}$ giving the connection strength between a unit in channel $i$ of the output and a unit in channel $j$ of the input, with an offset of $k$ rows and $l$ columns between the output unit and input unit.
>
> Assume our input consists of observed data $\mathsf{V}$ with element $V_{i, j, k}$ giving the value of the input unit within channel $i$ at row $j$ and column $k$.
>
> Assume our output consist of $\mathsf{Z}$ with the same format as $\mathsf{V}$. If $\mathsf{Z}$ is produced by convolving $\mathsf{K}$ across $\mathsf{V}$ without flipping $\mathsf{K}$, then:
>
> $$ Z_{i,\ j,\ k} = \sum_{l,\ m,\ n} V_{l,\ j + m - 1,\ k + n - 1} \times K_{i,\ l,\ m,\ n}$$
>
> where the summation over $l$, $m$, and $n$ is over all values for which the tensor indexing operations inside the summation are valid.

I suppose that it's not hard to see that the equation is depicting the dot product between a filter and a "patch" in the input data. But I don't particularly understand how the authors came up with this equation. My original knowledge of the convolution operation for neural networks is like [this demo provided by Stanford University's CS231n course](http://cs231n.github.io/assets/conv-demo/index.html).

I suppose that if I were to summarize what's particularly puzzling me, it would be as follows:

1. My understanding regarding convolution is that the number of channels of an input image and the number of channels in a filter (or kernel) need to match, and that typically each channel only convolves with its corresponding channel. However, the definition given by the authors here (i.e. "between a unit in channel $i$ of the output and a unit in channel $j$ of the input") seems to imply that the number of channels doesn't have to match and that there may be convolution between different channels in the input and filter. Is cross-convolution across different channels possible?
2. What is meant by "an offset of $k$ rows and $l$ columns between the output unit and input unit" in the first paragraph? Is this simply referring to the filter's size (i.e. $k \times l$)?
3. It seems that the authors are also assuming that the output $\mathsf{Z}$ (i.e. the result of the dot product between a filter and the input patch) and input $\mathsf{V}$ are the same size. However, my knowledge tells me that after performing a convolution between an input and filter, the output feature map is always smaller than the input. Why are the authors assuming that the size is the same? Is this even possible?

Comment: What do you not understand in my answer ? A convolution means for input vector/array $x(n)$ sending it to $\sum_k c_k x(n-k)$ : so $x(n-k)$ is a shifted version of $x(n)$ and the convolution is summing the different shifted versions weighted by the filter coefficients $c_k$. There is quite nothing else to say, you are making big deal for nothing (the implementation details). I  made clear how they arrived to that formula.

Comment: Yes, your answer was very concise and had information regarding the convolution operation. However, my original question(s) wasn't particularly about the derivation or the meaning of the equation itself, but rather the differences between the commonly-known implementation in CNN's vs. the mathematical equation presented in the book. I believe the implementation details themselves are a big part of the question, and in my opinion saying that I'm "making a big deal for nothing" contradicts the entire purpose of a Q&A forum.

Comment: In real life the point is to choose the size of the filters, the initialization, and in many cases instead of making it general to generate its coefficients from another formula, for example a low-pass filter is very large but it has slowly varying coefficients so it is generated only from a few parameters. In RNN libs it means the filter coefs will be the output of other neurons. What else do you not understand ? In RNN libs instead of reading the documentation, set the filter coefs to $[1,1],[1,-1]$, put a few Dirac deltas in input and see what is the ouput.

Comment: Your channel paragraph doesn't mean anything to me : make it clear with formulas. We can convolve two 2d arrays of any size.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula means

$$Z_i = \sum_l  V_l \ast K_{i,l}$$

(where $\ast$ is 2d convolution, over your $j,k$ variables, $Z_i , V_l,K_{i,l}$ are 2d arrays)

A convolution is a weighted sum of shifts of the input, the "offset" is the shift.

So it is the same formula as for fully connected (linear) layers except that the activation of each neuron is a 2d array, same for the weights, and instead of multiplying the activation and weight we convolve.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer. What exactly does "offset" mean in this context?

Comment: Did you read my answer ? Do you have troubles seing how a convolution is a weighted sum of shifts of the input ? Offset = shift

Comment: Could have been better without the unnecessary meanness. Yes I read your answer, but it's not really answering any of the questions that I asked except maybe number 2. When you say "shift" you're referring to the term "stride" that's more commonly used in CNN literature, right?